# Show that if $A_n \to A$ then $P(A_n) \to P(A)$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

Here $P$ is probability. I can do this for $A_n \uparrow A$ by using $\sigma$-additivity:

$$B_n = A_n - A_{n-1}$$

$$P(A) = P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n\right) = P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n\right)$$

$$P(A) = P\left(\lim_{n\to \infty } \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} B_n\right) = \lim_{n\to \infty } \sum_{i=1}^{n} P(B_n)$$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \sum_{i=1}^{n} P(B_n) = \lim_{n\to \infty }P(A_n)$$

But this relies on the fact that $\bigcup_{i=1}^n B_i = \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$, which I can't assume if $A_n$ does not monotonically converge to $A$. What should I do?

Comment: How do you define $A_n \to A$ for sets?

Comment: When the $limsup = liminf$ but I'm not sure how to use that

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2407187/a-liminfa-n-limsupa-n-then-pa-n-to-pa?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A = \bigcap_n \bigcup_{k \ge n} A_k = \bigcup_n \bigcap_{k \ge n} A_k$ and so
$P(A) = \lim_n P (\cup_{k \ge n} A_k) = \lim_n P (\bigcap_{k \ge n} A_k)$.

Now note that $\bigcap_{k \ge n} A_k \subset A_n \subset \bigcup_{k \ge n} A_k$.

Answer (score 3):

$A_n\to A$ (i.e. $\limsup A_n=\liminf A_n=A$) iff $1_{A_n}\to 1_A$ pointwise. Then $$
\mathsf{E}1_{A_n}\to\mathsf{E}1_A=\mathsf{P}(A)
$$
by the [bounded convergence theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235511/explanation-of-the-bounded-convergence-theorem).